# Instance variables not working in ViewController in UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm still new to iOS development but I've ran into a problem that I can't solve and I've tried looking online but can't find anything yet.

I'm using a UIImagePickerController to pick and image and I'm using it in the App Delegate. When an image is returned, in the imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method, I want to make a new navigation controller with a view controller and put it over the "app".

Here is how I'm doing it:

```
CustomNavigationController *customNavigationController = [[CustomNavigationController alloc] init];
PhotoViewController *photoViewController = [[PhotoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhotoViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[customNavigationController pushViewController:photoViewController animated:NO];
[customNavigationController.view setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

[photoViewController release];
[self.window addSubview:customNavigationController.view];

//Call method of photoViewController.
[[customNavigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] addPhotoFromData:info];

[self.tabBarController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; //Get rid of UIImagePickerController
```

However in the photoViewController, I don't have access to any instance variables synthesized and loaded in viewDidLoad. They all return to null. There is also a tableView and calls to reload the tableView do not actually cause the tableView to respond.

Here is some of the code from photoViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.photoCount = 0;
    self.timestamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    self.photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
    self.photosData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
    self.uploadingCount = 0;

    UINib *customCell = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomTableCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [self.tableView registerNib:customCell forCellReuseIdentifier:@"customCell"];
    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    NSLog(@"%@", self);
}
```

and also the addPhotoFromData method:

```
- (void)addPhotoFromData:(NSDictionary *)info
{    
   [self.photos addObject:info];
   NSLog(@"%@", self.photos); //Doesn't add "info" and does not return anything when later called from other methods.

   [self.tableView reloadData]; //Doesn't work
```

Everything was working before I add in the UINavigationController. I'm completely lost.

**EDIT:** After some more debugging attempts, I have discovered that the view is not loaded when addPhotoFromData is called. viewDidLoad is called afterwords. Is there a way to delay method calls?

Comment: Why do you need to make a new navigation controller? Just push a new view on the current one.

Comment: It's a tabbed application and I want to kind of replicate Instagram where if you press the middle tab you can take the photo and then it goes another view where you can't see the tab bar. I need another view after that so I assumed I should use a navigation controller.

Comment: Also if I push another view controller over the initial photoViewController, there is no problem with instance variables there.

Comment: Can't you just hide the `TabBar` when you're in the new view?

Comment: That's a good idea. But I also realized that [addPhotoFromData] is called before viewDidLoad of that view controller is called so no wonder it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason you can't have the PhotoViewController call `addPhotoFromData:` inside the `viewDidLoad` method?  You can always access properties of the app delegate from the view controller:

```
YourAppDelegateType * delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[self addPhotoFromData:delegate.info];
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. [You should also include your AppDelegate.h file to make this work :)]